# How to display default value in JSON Schema using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I am using Jackson to create json schema. I want to display property with their default value in json schema. I tried @JsonProperty annotation with default attribute but still default value is not being display on the json schema.

I am using following code to generate Json Schema:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonSchemaGenerator schemaGen = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
            JsonSchema schema = null;
            try {
                 schema = schemaGen.generateSchema(RootTemplate.class);
                 System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(schema));
            } 
            catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                 e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: The built-in Jackson jsonschema generation is not actively maintained anymore (also visible from the fact that it supports only a rather old JSON schema draft version). You might be better off going for an alternative way of generating your JSON schema. There are a couple better libraries out there already. Which may also support picking up default values more or less out-of-the-box.

Comment: @Carsten Could you suggest some better libraries ?

Comment: I was trying to avoid self-advertising. The most established follow-up in my view is the [mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema](https://github.com/mbknor/mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema). Then there would be [JJSchema](https://github.com/reinert/JJSchema) and (my own) [victools/jsonschema-generator](https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator). There are some more, but these are the two most popular I‘d say and mine (which I‘m obviously biased about), which allows you to configure what you want but doesn’t do it out-of-the-box. I’m not sure about the other two though.