# Library for Json Schema and Validation in Java

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I can see there are some libraries that generate Json Schema and other which can validate. Could you please suggest some library (with examples and active one) that can provide both functionality in Java. I am looking for Apache licensed library.

I have tried Jackson and Gson.
Gson does not support neither json schema creation and validation.
Jackson support json schema generation but not fully (e.g. it does not support default value in json schema)

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main scope of GSON and Jackson is to handle the serialization/deserialization of your data to/from JSON.
Both the generation and validation of JSON Schemas are not their (main) concern.

As per comments on your other question ([How to display default value in JSON Schema using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61124672/5127499)), there are a couple of alternatives out there for the schema generation – the same applies to their validation.

#### List of Implementations (Generation & Validation)

As per `R.Groote`'s answer, you can find some (but not all) of them on https://json-schema.org/implementations.html – both generation and validation libraries.

#### Validation

Personally, I've only used [networknt/json-schema-validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator) so far and found it very intuitive and easy to use. It uses Jackson under the hood, which was practical in my use-case as I was already using the same library for the (de)serialization of data from/to JSON – so less additional dependencies.

---

#### Generation

> Disclaimer: here comes the biased part as I'm the creator of
>   [victools/jsonschema-generator](https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator).

One example for a JSON Schema generation library would be [victools/jsonschema-generator](https://github.com/victools/jsonschema-generator). That also uses Jackson internally, so again similar dependencies to the [networknt/json-schema-validator](https://github.com/networknt/json-schema-validator).

The `jsonschema-generator` library does not populate the "default" value out-of-the-box, but you could easily configure it like this (based on the Jackson `@JsonProperty` annotation as per your other question):

```java
SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder configBuilder = new SchemaGeneratorConfigBuilder(SchemaVersion.DRAFT_2019_09, OptionPreset.PLAIN_JSON);
configBuilder.forFields().withDefaultResolver(field -> {
    JsonProperty annotation = field.getAnnotationConsideringFieldAndGetter(JsonProperty.class);
    return annotation == null || annotation.defaultValue().isEmpty() ? null : annotation.defaultValue());
});
SchemaGenerator generator = new SchemaGenerator(configBuilder.build());
JsonNode jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(YourClass.class);

System.out.println(jsonSchema.toString());
```

If you are catering for numeric default values, you might have to include some conditional parsing of the `@JsonProperty.defaultValue` `String` then.

Additionally, if you want some more specific handling of Jackson annotations you could also consider adding the optional `victools/jsonschema-module-jackson` as well then.

---

#### EDIT (as response to your concerns having to define the default values twice – in the code and on the annotation):

With the `victools/jsonschema-generator` you have full control over where the default value is coming from. One possible approach could be to look-up the default values from actual instances of the respective objects being encountered – here filtering by your own package to skip external types.
The following is just a rough example of what is possible:

```java
ConcurrentMap<Class<?>, Object> instanceCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
configBuilder.forFields().withDefaultResolver(field -> {
    Class<?> declaringClass = field.getDeclaringType().getErasedType();
    if (!field.isFakeContainerItemScope()
            && declaringClass.getName().startsWith("your.package")) {
        MethodScope getter = field.findGetter();
        if (getter != null) {
            try {
                Object instance = instanceCache.computeIfAbsent(declaringClass, declaringClass::newInstance);
                Object defaultValue = getter.getRawMember().invoke(instance);
                return defaultValue;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // most likely missing a no-args constructor
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please answer this question as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140930/how-to-exclude-primitive-types-from-required-list-of-json-schema-version4

Comment: I saw the question but cannot answer it. I have never used the mbknor library but found it unsuitable for my very specific use-case while investigating for an existing generator library and ended up writing my own.

Comment: I think there is one more problem with default value. If I use the annotation JsonProperty(defaultValue="abc"). This annotation will be respected while generating schema but it wont be respected while deserializing the json to POJO via Jackson. It means I will have to specify the default value at two places (Annotation and assignment) for each property

Comment: Possibly, yes. According to the annotation‘s JavaDoc, the annotated default value is intended for documentation purposes. Looks like you’re right. You could also lookup the default value from code if you follow certain conventions in your code. E.g. if there is always a no-args constructor and getters for all fields with default values, you could always create a new object instance and retrieve the default value via the getter.

Comment: Yes, But still I will have to specify default values at multiple places. I am not sure if I can override or extend Jackson deserialize process and check if @JsonProperty associated with the property with default value.

Comment: You should have both options: customise the deserialisation process in Jackson as you said, or in case of my `jsonschema-generator` you could not set it on the `@JsonProperty` at all and configure it so that it creates an instance of each object and calls the getters to determine the default values for all fields.

Comment: @Tarun I've edited my answer and added an example for looking up the default values without having to define anything on `@JsonProperty`  annotations.

Comment: Thanks It looks really good. I will give it a try.

Comment: Does the library support features like "anyof" ,"if" etc ?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: some things are supported out-of-the-box (e.g. certain usages of `anyOf`) others you‘d have to configure yourself (which you can do down to the individual nodes in the schema).

Comment: Actually, I want to put condition like if value of "foo" is equal to "baaz", then "abc" should be required.

Comment: As stated above, you have full control over what goes into the schema. So that’s definitely possible. Maybe rather log an issue with a specific example on the GitHub repository and I can give you more concrete explanations.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use GSON or Jackson:
- https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-vs-gson

You could use Justify or json-schema-validator see below links:
- https://json-schema.org/implementations.html
- [Validate JSON schema compliance with Jackson against an external schema file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179086/validate-json-schema-compliance-with-jackson-against-an-external-schema-file)

I hope the above links give you enough information